# Simple JS Math Contains an error and I have no clue how to fix it

Tags: javascript, math

I am having an issue with my math `function(doMath())`. I have exhausted everything I know on how to get this to work. I have posted my code here, but I'm at a loss as to what's wrong. It was working when the form was simpler, but I added a few new features to it.  If you don't mind helping me out on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
function  doMath() {
var one = document.getElementById('price').value;
var two = document.getElementById('recon').value;
var outp = "";
var outps = "";
    {
    ans = (one*two);
    ansq = (one*two)*12;
    outp =" " + "$" + ans.toFixed(2) + "/Month";
    outps =" " + "$" + ansq.toFixed(2) + "/Year";

}
  document.getElementById('outtab').innerHTML = outp;
document.getElementById('outtab1').innerHTML = outps;
}
```

Comment: When posting a question, one should assume that the reader does not **want** to do any work to try to figure out what it is asking...

Comment: Go back to where it was working, and add ONE new feature at a time.

Comment: When you want us to help you fix something, you should first tell us what's not working, instead of making people guess what the problem might be. "I am having an issue" is meaningless.

Comment: The Function doMath() is not calculating the math, I am not sure why its not working.  Its like it wont find the places it needs.

Comment: I feel scammed. The title says `simple`

Comment: DO NOT USE EVAL! BAD BAD BAD! Use parseInt, parseFloat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi :) I have decided to try and fix your code. I'll walk you through what I did to figure out what was wrong.

First off, I copied all of your code to my computer, and tested it as is.

It would appear that, when clicking the "Calculate Total" button is pressed... Nothing happens. I also notice that the "Yearly"/"Monthly total" is blank... As such, I assume that your problem is that nothing ever happens to those displays.

My first thought was that perhaps the button was broken -- In other words, it was not calling doMath()! To check this, I added alert("domath called"); inside the domath() method. As I suspected, no popup occurred. This means that the button was not made correctly, and is not calling doMath!

After figuring this out, I immediately checked out your button HTML. Turns out, it looked valid! COnfused, I took one more look at your function, and noticed some strange syntax. I tried removing it, and that failed. I decided to completely remove your JS and replace it with my own JS, to see if MY copy of the code would work. IF it did, then this would point to syntax issues. RIGHT as I was about to do this, I noticed something very odd.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

Language SHOULD be type.

I replaced language with type, and... It worked!

I re-added your strange syntax to see if it had any effect as well. It did not. As such, I can conclude that there is exactly ONE issue with your source. The solution is simple:

Change

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The FULL code, with that one change applied is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Package Plans</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function  doMath() {
var one = eval(document.theForm.elements[0].value);
var two = eval(document.theForm.elements[1].value);
var outp = "";
var outps = "";
    {
    ans = (one*two);
    ansq = (one*two)*12;
    outp =" " + "$" + ans.toFixed(2) + "/Month";
    outps =" " + "$" + ansq.toFixed(2) + "/Year";
}
  document.getElementById('outtab').innerHTML = outp;
document.getElementById('outtab1').innerHTML = outps;
} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reconPackage(){
var text = document.getElementById('recom');
var rad=document.theForm.gb;
for(var i=0;i<rad.length;i++){
    if(rad[i].checked){
        switch(rad[i].value){
        case '5':text = '5';break;
        case '10':text = '10';break;
        case '15':text = '15';break;
        case '20':text = '20';break;
        case '30':text = '30';break;
        case '50':text = '50';break;
        case '100':text = '100';break;
        default: text='';break;
        }
        }
}
document.getElementById('recom').innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcPackage(){
var text = document.getElementById('price');
var rad=document.theForm.gb;
for(var i=0;i<rad.length;i++){
    if(rad[i].checked){
        switch(rad[i].value){
        case '5':text.value = '2.50';break;
        case '10':text.value = '2.00';break;
        case '15':text.value = '2.00';break;
        case '20':text.value = '1.75';break;
        case '30':text.value = '1.25';break;
        case '50':text.value = '0.80';break;
        case '100':text.value = '0.50';break;
        default: text='';break;
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoAllThese() {
calcPackage();
reconPackage();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="one" name="theForm" onClick="DoAllThese()">
            <p><strong>Choose package that fits you best, then click the button below to get a price:</strong><br/>              
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="5">I just use my computer for email and surfing the web.  I have a few documents and other files I need to back up.<br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="10">
            I have some music and a few files, I am in school/college and need to backup my work.<br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="15">
            I have 50 songs, pictures, and documents, I do not want to lose.
            <br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="20">
            I have a lot of documents that need to be backed up regulary, plus some music.<br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="30">
            I own small business and need to backup a few computers.<br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="50">
            I have a few 100 songs, and need to protect them!<br/>
            <input   type="radio" name="gb" value="100">I'm a music and picture hound.  My life's collection of MP3s and every picture I've ever taken is on my computer.<br/>
            <p>Recommend Package: <span id="recom"></span> GB Plan</p>
            </p>


  <p>
  </p>
  <div>$<input name="two" type="text" DISABLED id="price" size="8"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="doMath();" value="Calculate Total"><input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
<BR><BR>Monthly Total:<SPAN ID="outtab"></SPAN>
<br>Yearly Total:<SPAN ID="outtab1"></SPAN>
</form>
<br><BR>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are using this for commercial purposes, I REALLY implore you to redo your code completely. It seems very overcomplicated, such as using eval, and reading from two form-elements when only one is ever set. It's like you are storing data in the form which could be stored in one var.

Comment: I have taken the suggestion and applied it.  Thanks it did work. I also revised my code a bit and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear :D If you would please click the check-mark next to my answer, that earns me points, and would be very much appreciated!